# Applications of the Modularity Theorem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Besides its role in proving Fermat's Last Theorem and its well-known consequence that the $L$-function of an elliptic curve is defined at 1 (so that, in particular, the BSD Conjecture makes sense), what are the other applications of the Modularity Theorem? Wikipedia cites one: the sum of coprime $n$th powers can never be a cube, but gives no reference. I am after as many consequences as you all can provide, as I will be compiling them to present to a seminar this summer.

Comment: Sato–Tate conjecture ? In my understanding it is about proving the PNT for the symmetric power L-functions $L(s,\pi_E^{\otimes n})$